# Running the converted py to exe file shows a console and not the designed GUI

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I want to create a GUI EXE file
I am creating a a GUI using python 3.6 and PyQt5, After running .py file I get the design that I worked on.
However when i convert the .py file to an exe using Cx_Freeze or pyinstaller, then I run the EXE file, GUI doesn't show and a console shows instead.

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

completed = 0
accumulate = 0
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        loadUi('progress.ui',self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Greeting')
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.increase.clicked.connect(self.increase_by10)
        self.reset.clicked.connect(self.resetprogress)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def increase_by10(self):
        global accumulate
        accumulate += 10
        if accumulate <= 100:
                self.progressBar.setValue(accumulate)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def resetprogress(self):
        global accumulate
        accumulate = 0
        self.progressBar.setValue(accumulate)
        
      
              
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = Main()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: design]

[image: running exe file shows a console]

- running .py file
- running .exe converted from .py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ...\Python\Scripts\pyuic5.exe progress.ui  -o progress.py  -x
2. ## + (progress.py)    # - (progress.ui)
3. pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py
4. main.exe

main.py

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QThread       #++++++++ QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
#from PyQt5.uic import loadUi                     #--------

import progress                                  #++++++++

completed = 0
accumulate = 0
class Main(QMainWindow, progress.Ui_MainWindow): #++++++++ progress.Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)                       #+++++++++
        #loadUi('progress.ui',self)              #---------

        self.setWindowTitle('Greeting')
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.increase.clicked.connect(self.increase_by10)
        self.reset.clicked.connect(self.resetprogress)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def increase_by10(self):
        global accumulate
        #accumulate += 10                              #-----
        while accumulate <= 100:                       #+++++ 
            self.progressBar.setValue(accumulate)
            QThread.msleep(1000)                       #+++++
            accumulate += 10                           #+++++


    @pyqtSlot()
    def resetprogress(self):
        global accumulate
        accumulate = 0
        self.progressBar.setValue(accumulate)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = Main()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```